# Difference between [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; & self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

## Edited

Can someone please explain the difference between `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];` and `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;`

Comment: The former doesn't exists. Did you mean `setSelectedIndex:`?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are the same, technically `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]` is calling the setter method and `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;` is calling the setter using "dot syntax". Both have the same behavior.

As [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) says when using `@property` the getter and setter methods for that property are generated automatically (synthesized automatically).

Also is important to know that, as @Duncan C mentioned, you can bypass the setter by setting directly the iVar.

Comment: lActually, both are calling the setter. Any time you use `self.property = value` in you are invoking the setter. It's just syntactic sugar ("dot syntax") for exactly the same thing as the other version with square brackets. Now if you say `iVar = value` instead of `self.iVar = value` you are bypassing the setter and modifying the instance variable directly. (Swift makes no such distinction between instance variables and properties with getters and setters)